# How to call a function on all of an object's properties?

Tags: javascript, arrays, constructor

I am making a game where I have multiple tile objects stored in an array, and I am trying to call a function "update", to draw the tiles to the screen.

My script:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("game canvas");
canvas.width = 600;
canvas.height = 300;
var g = canvas.getContext("2d");
var grass = new Image();
grass.src = "grass.png";
setInterval(draw,1000/60);

function tile(x,y,img) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.img = img;
    this.update = function() {
        g.drawImage(this.img,this.x,this.y);
    }
}
var maps = {
    map1:{
        tiles:[
            new tile(0,0,grass),
            new tile(0,32,grass)
        ],

        update:function() {
            for (var i in this.tiles) {
                i.update();
            }
        }
    }
};

function draw() {
    maps.map1.update();
}
```

I also tried using an object instead of an array for the tile container, but it didn't work either. It outputs this error into the console:

```
TypeError: i.update is not a function
```

Comment: try i.apply(null,update)

Comment: Search for "JavaScript, iterate array" and "JavaScript, for in".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-array-in-javascript/3010848#3010848

Answer (score 1):

When you use a for...in loop, `i` is actually referring to the property name of the object. In this case, `tiles` is an array, so `i` can be thought of as an index into that array (Be careful though, Arrays in JS are basically just special objects with indices as property names).

**HOWEVER** as @jfriend00 pointed out in the comments, `for..in` will enumerate over all properties of an object and therefore can access some things that might not be what you expect, or objects that don't have an `update()` to call.

While you can do this:

```
update:function() {
    for (var i in this.tiles) {

        // get the current tile
        this.tiles[i].update();
    }
}
```

**It is better** to use either a `forEach` loop on your array, or use a standard `for` loop:

```
update:function() {

    // update each tile
    this.tiles.forEach(function(tile) {
        tile.update();
    }
}
```

or

```
update:function() {

    // normal for loop for safe indexing
    for (var i = 0; i < this.tiles.length; i++) {
        this.tiles[i].update();
    }
}
```

[More info](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/11/myths-and-realities-of-forin.html) on for-in

[SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476) that talks about all types of iteration techniques

Comment: You should never use the structure `for (var i in this.tiles)` on an array.  That iterates all enumerable properties of the array (which may include some properties of the object), not only array elements.  You can safely use `for (var i = 0; i < this.tiles.length; i++)` or `this.tiles.forEach(...)` instead.